# Quais são as principais situações onde não devemos usar vírgula de forma alguma?

Tags: pontuação

Existem frases onde é proibido o uso de vírgula.
Sei que não devemos usar virgula de forma alguma entre o **sujeito** e o **predicado**, mesmo se houver inversão. Exemplo:

> A atual crise econômica gerou inúmeros comentários acerca do país no exterior.

Neste caso, não empregamos vírgula após o sujeito "**A atual crise econômica**". Também não existe vírgula entre o verbo "**gerou**" e o seu complemento.

Quais são as principais situações onde não devemos usar vírgula de forma alguma?

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil indicar em que casos é que a vírgula é permitida ou obrigatória.

Comment: Concordo com a sugestão de E_net4. (Nunca use a virgula antes do ponto: `,.`.)

Comment: Esta questão é demasiado abrangente e não é respondível de forma completa. Devia ser editada para fazer uma pergunta mais concreta e restrita.

Comment: Não é tão ampla assim. De qualquer forma, inclui a palavra "principais" na pergunta. Na minha opinião saber os casos onde é proibido o uso de vírgula ajuda muito. Vi em um site algumas regras que ajudam muito, vou elaborar a resposta depois.

Comment: Nenhuma frase SVP (sujeito-verbo-predicado) não precisa de vírgula. Eis uma regra fácil. E algumas SV também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sobre o uso da vírgula é proibido separar:

1) O sujeito do verbo:
**O povo** elegeu Lula como presidente do Brasil.
**Os maiores problemas do Brasil** estão na sua própria formação.

2) O verbo do complemento ou predicativo.
O povo **elegeu** Lula como presidente do Brasil.
(verbo do objeto direto)

Nós **permanecíamos** apreensivos.
(verbo do predicativo)

3) Oração principal de oração subordinada substantiva objetiva ou predicativa.
**Desejo** que todos sejam aprovados.

**Convém** que você estude!

4) Substantivo de Adjunto Adnominal.
Pelé foi eleito Rei `,` do futebol.
(erro ao separar o substantivo do adjunto adnominal)

5) Oração coordenada sindética aditiva com o mesmo sujeito
Paulo e João trabalham `,` e estudam muito
(erro ao separar sujeitos iguais em oração coordenada)

Adaptado de [Português para Concursos](http://www.portuguesconcurso.com/2009/11/proibidao-da-virgula-concurso.html).

Comment: Ok, corrigido. Obrigado

Comment: No ponto 1, há exceções: vários gramáticos aceitam separar por vírgula sujeitos oracionais do verbo (*quem sabe, sabe* ou *a razão por que não quero ir, só a mim diz respeito*); Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/%C3%89-mesmo-sempre-proibido-separar-por-v%C3%ADrgula-o-sujeito-do-verbo).