# É mesmo sempre proibido separar por vírgula o sujeito do verbo?

Tags: pontuação, ambiguidades

A resposta a esta [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/655/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-principais-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-onde-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-de-forma-alguma), baseada numa “mini” gramática online, diz que sim. Mas eu creio que já vi sujeitos separado do verbo por vírgula quando o sujeito é longo. Vejamos o seguinte exemplo:

> A razão por que não quero ir só a mim diz respeito.

Eu estaria tentado a inserir uma vírgula nesta frase. Até porque, tal como está, a frase é ambígua. Não sabemos se o sujeito é “a razão por que não quero ir” ou “a razão por que não quero ir só. Na fala, a ambiguidade é desfeita por um ligeira pausa; e será também desfeita  na escrita se marcarmos a pausa por vírgula:

> A razão por que não quero ir, só a mim diz respeito.
>
> A razão por que não quero ir só, a mim diz respeito.

Estas vírgulas são permitidas? Em que casos, se é que existem, é permitido separar o sujeito do verbo por vírgula? Naturalmente, não estamos a pensar em apostos ou orações explicativas intercaladas e isoladas por vírgulas, como “o João, o meu colega, também vem” ou “essa explicação, que não é nova, é enganosa”.

Comment: Em hipótese alguma, é permitida a separação do sujeito + verbo. A vírgula após o verbo "ir" parece-me correta. *A razão por que não quero ir*, ao meu ver, é a *oração subordinada substantiva subjetiva* do verbo *dizer*. A frase também pode ser escrita da seguinte forma: *A razão por que não quero ir diz respeito somente a mim.*

Comment: **Quem quiser conhecer melhor os candidatos a vereador, prefeito e vice-prefeito nas eleições deste ano (sujeito)** [não separa sujeito do verbo] *conta (verbo)* com uma ferramenta virtual desenvolvida pelo Tribunal Superior Eleitoral (TSE). Fonte do Exemplo: https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/virgula

Comment: @Valdeir, no teu primeiro comentário, queres dizer "parece-me **in**correta", não? Pelo tom geral do comentário...  Pelos vistos (vê resposta do Artefacto), estas vírgulas são permitidas ou mesmo recomendadas por pelo menos alguns gramáticos. Naturalmente, não sendo obrigatórias, o Senado pode preferir não as usar.

Comment: O "hipótese alguma" foi um exagero, reconheço isso (até então eu desconhecia a regra do Bechara). Entretanto é uma regra tradicional (não separar o sujeito do verbo). Pesquisei mais a fundo e encontrei uma afirmação do professor **Luiz A. Sacconi**: *Em orações substantivas com função de sujeito iniciadas por quem, a vírgula entre tal oração e o verbo da principal é facultativa*. Porém, o professor **Fernando Pestana** afirma: *Os demais gramáticos nada falam sobre isso, logo deduzimos que não pode haver vírgula entre sujeito e verbo.*

Comment: @Valdeir, quer-me parecer que há gramáticos  que querem elevar certos princípios a uma espécie de lei divina, e não admitem exceções nem mesmo quando exista justificação para ela, como um vírgula entre o sujeito e verbo que facilite a leitura. Já me deparei com uma atitude dessas quando consultei o Ciberdúvidas a propósito de "um terço das mulheres está grávida", que viola a concordância gramatical; podes ver o que se passou [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/um-ter%C3%A7o-das-mulheres-presentes-pode-estar-gr%C3%A1vida).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, não é sempre proibido. No caso da tua frase, não creio que haja ambiguidade (a leitura em que *só* modifica *ir* dá origem a uma ordem estranha nos constituintes da frase matriz), mas a vírgula certamente ajuda a ler a frase.

Cláudio Moreno tem [um artigo precisamente sobre este assunto](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/08/02/virgula-depois-de-sujeito-oracional/). A ideia fundamental é a de que a pontuação deve ajudar à descodificação da frase:

> Não se trata, aqui, de voltar àquela antiga visão de pontuação subjetiva, submetida ao simples capricho de quem escreve; bem pelo contrário: a finalidade exclusiva dos sinais de pontuação é **orientar o leitor no trabalho de decodificar as frases que escrevemos**.

Em particular:

> O princípio geral é muito simples: como devemos reservar a vírgula para assinalar tudo aquilo que foge à normalidade sintática, é evidente que não há razão para separar o sujeito do verbo, nem o verbo de seu complemento, já que esta é a ordem canônica da frase no Português. Todavia, quando o sujeito for **oracional** (representado por uma oração subordinada **substantiva**), os bons escritores empregam, muitas vezes, uma vírgula para assinalar com maior clareza o fim do bloco do sujeito.

E identifica três casos em que a vírgula é recomendada ou mesmo indispensável:

> - construção paralela, em que o verbo da oração substantiva é seguido imediatamente pelo verbo da oração principal: “**Quem quer**, faz; **quem não quer**, manda”
> - se o verbo for idêntico nas duas orações, esta vírgula passa a ser indispensável: “**Quem deu**, dará; **quem pediu**, pedirá”. “**Quem vai**, vai; **quem fica**, fica”
> - casos em que a forma verbal pode se confundir com um substantivo homógrafo, criando-se uma ambigüidade que a vírgula desmancha imediatamente: “**Quem quiser**, peça”

No mesmo sentido vai Evanildo Bechara, na sua *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*:

> **Vírgula** – Emprega-se a vírgula:
>   [...]
>   h) para separar, quase sempre, as orações adjetivas restritivas de
>   certa extensão, principalmente quando os verbos de duas orações
>   diferentes se juntam [...]
>
> Observação: Esta pontuação pode ocorrer ainda que separe por vírgula o
>   sujeito expandido pela oração adjetiva:
>
> > Os que falam em matérias que não entendem, parecem fazer gala da
> >     sua própria ignorância

Este último exemplo (onde a vírgula é recomendável por termos os dois verbos de seguida) está mais perto da tua frase do que os de Cláudio Moreno, porque enquanto o último dá apenas exemplos com subordinadas substantivas relativas (sem antecedente expresso), na tua frase há precisamente uma oração adjetiva relativa restritiva separada por vírgula (*os que* não é um morfema relativo, embora aqui até pudesse ser substituído por *quem*).

Comment: De facto, nem me tinha lembrado de "quem sabe, sabe" e coisas do tipo. Sim, a frase que primeiro me veio à cabeça, foi "a razão por que não quero ir, só a mim diz respeito". Dizes que "...ir só, a mim diz respeito" gera uma ordem estranha porquê? É simplesmente por nós esperarmos naturalmente "só a mim diz respeito" e não apenas "a mim diz respeito"?

Comment: @Jacinto porque nesse caso o objeto indireto viria antes do verbo. O mais normal seria _a razão por que não quero ir só, diz-me respeito (é) a mim._ ou uma clivada-Q com _é a mim a quem diz respeito por que razão não quero ir só_. Com um significado diferente, podias usar uma topicalização/deslocação à esqda clítica: _a mim, diz(-me) respeito a razão por que não quero ir só_.

Comment: O objeto direto vem antes do verbo nos dois casos: "...ir, só a mim diz..." ou "ir só, a mim diz". Evidentemente, que te soa mais normal a ti não soa a mim. Nada contra as tuas reformulações, mas eu tenderia nos dois casos ("...ir, só a mim..." ou "...ir só, a mim...") a puxar o "a mim" para a esquerda. A reforçar, diria "a razão por que não quero ir só, é a mim que diz respeito".

Comment: @Jacinto, no teu último exemplo, a vírgula após **só**, não o tornaria sinônimo de *sozinho*, enquanto a vírgula antes do **só**, tornaria-o sinônimo de *somente*?

Comment: @Valdeir, é isso mesmo. Na verdade, eu tendo a dizer "ir sozinho" mais do que "ir só".

Comment: @Valdeir, esses sinónimos seriam uma maneira de resolver a ambiguidade. Mas a questão da ambiguidade aqui é secundária. Haveria muitas outras maneiras de a resolver. Eu estava mesmo interessado era na aceitabilidade da vírgula em casos destes.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, tens razão. De facto não sei por que razão _só_ torna aí a ordem SOV aceitável, que em geral é agramatical em português (*_O João a sopa comeu_, *_O João nisso acredita_). Mas de facto, o _o João só nisso acredita_ parece-me melhor (mas algo marginal) e _o João **nisso** acredita_ (com foco em _nisso_) sem problemas, tal como _esse assunto só ao João diz respeito_.

Comment: Queres dizer, não há problema em *nisso, o João acredita*? Não sei se tem algo que ver com o meio onde eu cresci, mas eu digo, e nunca notei que causasse estranheza a alguém, *a mim disse ele que vinha* (estando em discussão se ele vem ou não), *a mim não me engana ele, a mim já ele pediu dinheiro*.